# How do I prevent an overlay div from creating extra space at the bottom?

Tags: css, html

I have an HTML5 video on my website which is overlayed by a div that adds a cool color to it but for some reason it creates extra space at the bottom between it and the following section in my website (see image for reference)

[image: space between yellow and dark purple]

As you can see there's a small gap between the purple-ish overlay and the yellow section, basically, the overlay is not adapting to the video.

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="vid-overlay"></div>
    <div class="vid-container">
    <video autoplay loop>
       <source src="video/Hello-World2.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
       <source src="video/Hello-World2.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
      </video>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
video{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin:0;
  padding:0; 
}

#vid-overlay{
background: rgba(96,80,99,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(96,80,99,1) 0%, rgba(96,80,99,0.51) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, 
  position:absolute;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Try giving inline width height properties   for video element

Comment: You have a syntax error in your CSS snippet, after "color-stop(0%". Just sayin'

Answer (score 0):

Is `position:absolute` necessary for your requirements in the `vid-overlay` div.

If not Try :  `position:relative`.
This may solve your overlay error.

Answer (score 0):

The video tag defaults as an inline-block.  You need to make it display as a block element like this:

```
video {display: block;}
```